# There's an error when I trying to build App Bundle inn release mode

Tags: android-studio

when I tried to publish my app on google play  "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode" appeared, then I replaced "         signingConfig signingConfigs.debug" to " signingConfig signingConfigs.release" in build.gradle file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zGb6.png)

I tried "signingConfig signingConfigs.release" but faced that error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGVBL.png)